Find Latest Revision and Return Hyperlink using a Column to Search
hopefully one of you can help me out.
I'm making an Excel spreadsheet that imports a data file and compares the data with a couple of other sources, including file names, in a very large folder. The goal right now is to take a part number (text), find that part number in the folder query, combine the folder path with the file name, and create a hyperlink.
I'm almost done with the spreadsheet, but I can't figure out the hyperlink function. The issue is we have a revision process, so the first revision is "Rev01 (a)(b), PartNumber" and then "Rev02 (a)(b), PartNumber".  Most of the search/index functions I've seen use MAX() which only works with values not text. And the rest don't work at all.



Part Number to Lookup
FileName
Path




PartNumber1
Rev01 (a)(b), PartNumber1
C:\


PartNumber2
Rev02 (a)(b), PartNumber1
C:\



Rev01 (a)(b), PartNumber2
C:\



(One big thing for me is I only use spill formulas so I can reuse the sheet without worrying about dragging down formulas)
After a few more hours of searching and trying new formulas I found that if you use =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A2,B2:B4)),B2:B4,"") you get all FilesNames with the first PartNumber.



Result1




Rev01 (a)(b), PartNumber1


Rev02 (a)(b), PartNumber1






So, using BYROW and LAMBDA I built this monstrosity:
=HYPERLINK(BYROW(A2:A3,LAMBDA(row,LET(partnum,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(row,B2:B4)),C2:C4&B2:B4,""),filtered,FILTER(partnum,partnum<>""),INDEX(filtered,COUNTA(filtered)))))) 

The key idea for me was to use Result1 as an array and INDEX the new array to get the last value in the array (must be sorted in ascending order in this case which is easy with LET:
INDEX(filtered,COUNTA(filtered))




header 1




C:\Rev02 (a)(b), PartNumber1


C:\Rev01 (a)(b), PartNumber2



Now, my question is HYPERLINK() is only hyperlinking the first cell is there a way to hyperlink all of the cells? Also, is there an easier way to do this? This seems a bit complicated, but I could not find anything online.

HYPERLINK() don't work with spill arrays, it will always redirect to the first component/cell/row in the array. Please do some research on this topic, I am sure there two to three such posts where it has been discussed. You need to use copy down method. Dynamic Array Formulas aka DAF don't work with HYPERLINK() --> Read the comments in the following posted answer and one more read comments

Very nice effort! What's the version of Excel you're (and will be) using? Preferably get the info from 'About'.

nkalvi, I am using Microsoft Excel 365 MSO.

If the issue is avoiding the need to drag formulas down, try setting up your data range as an Excel table. Be aware that spilled array formulas don't work in tables, though. You can add data directly below a table (next row) and formulas will automatically fill down.

Thank you all. I did confirm that the HYPERLINK function only works for spill or dynamic array formulas (DAF) on the web version, not the desktop version. Appreciate the help!

As I have already stated HYPERLINK() function don't work with DAF Spill Arrays for now, it does work in Excel For Web for now, but that feature will not exist sooner or later. Also if you have local files trying to open from web it wont open, you will need to open on desktop, and again, in the array the link will always direct the first element in the array, so accepting an answer which doesn't work over desktop albeit for Excel for Web(temporarily), doesn't change the universal feature which has no documentations yet or updates. It only conveys wrong information to the community.

Spilling for HYPERLINK
A possible workaround for using HYPERLINK with spilled arrays:
pre-fill the range for links, accommodating for largest result set with first cell pointing to the cell with spill formula.
As in the example below:

In D2 enter HYPERLINK(E2), fill down
In E2 enter spill formula, with output in the form of
CONCAT("[", INDEX(filtered, COUNTA(filtered)), "]") instead of HYPERLINK(CONCAT…


This way we don't have to fill-down what's already spilled :)

If you haven't already, could you try this:
=BYROW(A2:A3, LAMBDA(row,
LET(partnum, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(row, B2:B4)), C2:C4 & B2:B4, ""),
filtered, FILTER(partnum, partnum <> ""),
HYPERLINK(CONCAT("[", INDEX(filtered, COUNTA(filtered)), "]")))))


Wrapping the link in [] is needed when the path has spaces.
In my testing the links are not formatted (with blue underlining) consistently (but the cursor turns to a pointer when hovering over), but are functioning correct as links.

Please test and let know.

Start a new line of text inside a cell in Excel - Microsoft Support

Optional - extract revision numbers to find max
Since you seem to like LAMBDAs, defining a helper function first_number in Name Manager to extract the revision number could be helpful. It's quickly put together function, you may find shorter ones elsewhere. My preferred way it to use REGEX, but it may not be available in your version of Excel yet.
first_number defined in Name Manager:
=LAMBDA(text,
    LET(
        len_, LEN(text),
        num_start, MIN(MAP(SEQUENCE(len_), LAMBDA(i, IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(text, i, 1)), i, len_ + 1)))),
        num_end, MIN(
            MAP(
                SEQUENCE(len_ - num_start + 1, , num_start),
                LAMBDA(i, IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(text, i, 1)), len_ + 1, i))
            )
        ),
        --MID(text, num_start, num_end - num_start)
    )
)



Then, instead of using the Part Number column, TEXTSPLIT can be used to extract the Part Number and Revision.
After extracting use the custom function to get max number

=LET(
    file_names, TOCOL(B2:B10, 1),
    paths, TOCOL(C2:C10, 1),
    revisions, TOCOL(TRIM(BYROW(file_names, LAMBDA(row, TEXTBEFORE(row, ",")))), 2),
    part_nums, TOCOL(TRIM(BYROW(file_names, LAMBDA(row, TEXTAFTER(row, ",")))), 2),
    rev_numbers, MAP(revisions, first_number),
    make_hyperlink, LAMBDA(path_and_file, HYPERLINK(CONCAT("[", path_and_file, "]"))),
    make_links, MAP(
        UNIQUE(part_nums),
        LAMBDA(part_num,
            LET(
                max_rev_num, MAX(FILTER(rev_numbers, part_nums = part_num)),
                path_and_file_for_latest, FILTER(
                    HSTACK(paths, file_names),
                    (part_nums = part_num) * (rev_numbers = max_rev_num)
                ),
                make_hyperlink(path_and_file_for_latest)
            )
        )
    ),
    make_links
)



Thank you for the bracket suggestion! That was very helpful and fixed my link issue. However, as pointed out by other users, the HYPERLINK() is broken for spill functions for on the desktop. You have to drag down the formula (or VBA). However, it works perfectly online. No issues when opening the web version of the document, so I'll submit a ticket along with the others to have them fix the bug.

You're most welcome, and thanks for the question :) I'm using the 'insider betaon Windows and theHYPERLINK spilledfromMAP` works as expected, i.e. for local files. Hopefully it will be available in regular channel soon.

@CoulterWilliams, after experimenting, I'm wondering about this workaround: pre-fill a column for links with relative ref to where the link will be filled by the spill formula.  For example, cell I2:i100 having =HYPERLINK(H2) filled down. Enter the spill formula in H2. Now the links seem to work as expected. It is better than filling down the original formula I think.
